# delimiter error when preg_replace with arrays

Tags: php, regex

I want to preg_replace some strings in an html file but the code below gives me error

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be
alphanumeric or backslash in /wamp/www/example.php on line 12
```

Line 12 is the `echo preg_replace($matches[0], $results, $sourcestring);`

```
$sourcestring=file_get_contents("example.html");
preg_match_all('/(?<=\/)\d+(?=\-)/',$sourcestring,$matches);
$results = array_unique($matches[0], SORT_NUMERIC);
$results = array_values($results);

for($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++) {
    $results[$i] = 'id="news-id-'.$results[$i].'"';
}

preg_match_all('/class="title"/', $sourcestring, $matches);
echo preg_replace($matches[0], $results, $sourcestring);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$matches[0]` value will be (something like) `class="title"`. You're using that as a regular expression in `preg_replace`. `class="title"` is not a valid regular expression, since it has no valid delimiters. A valid regex version would be `/class="title"/`.